# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string for comparing date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime, stored-procedures

I have assigned date value into a variable which is `2017-03-15T00:00:00+05:30`

and I am comparing with other date whose value is `TO_DATE('01-10-16', 'dd-mm-yy')`

So here is my query for the same

```
IF TO_DATE(r.FINAL_SR_DATE, 'dd-mm-yy') >= TO_DATE('01-10-16', 'dd-mm-yy')
  THEN
v_STD_REVISED_AMT_INT := (V_STANDRD_AMT - v_OD_Discount) + (V_STANDRD_AMT - v_OD_Discount) * 
 2.5/100;
```

But I am getting error as

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Please suggest how I can resolve the issue

Comment: what is the data type of `r.final_sr_date`?

Comment: the datatype is `NVARCHAR2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `'2017-03-15T00:00:00+05:30'` represents a timestamp with time zone. If you want to ignore the time and zone you could just use the date part of the string, but you still need to provide the correct format mask:

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(r.FINAL_SR_DATE, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

You could also keep the time part and ignore the time zone (if you're sure that's a valid thing to do):

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(r.FINAL_SR_DATE, 1, 19), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
```

although as you are comparing against a date at midnight the time part of your value is a bit irrelevant.

You should also use a 4-digit year for the right hand side of the comparison:

```
TO_DATE('01-10-2016', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

or more simply a date literal:

```
DATE '2016-10-01'
```

so you would end up with:

```
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(r.FINAL_SR_DATE, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= DATE '2016-10-01'
```

---

If you want to keep the time zone offset as well then you need a different data type:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(r.FINAL_SR_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
```

and then adjust the time zone if necessary, and compare with another timestamp with time zone value, which can also be a literal, e.g.:

```
TIMESTAMP DATE '2016-10-01 00:00:00 UTC'
```

or

```
TIMESTAMP DATE '2016-10-01 00:00:00+05:30'
```

so you woudl end up with:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(r.FINAL_SR_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')
  >= TIMESTAMP DATE '2016-10-01 00:00:00+05:30'
```

or whatever offset is appropriate for your environment; or preferably with a time zone region instead of an offset.

Comment: will that be doable ? `IF TO_DATE(SUBSTR(r.FINAL_SR_DATE, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD') > = TO_DATE(SUBSTR('2016-10-01', 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: The second substring is pointless as the literal '2016-10-01' is already the right length. But yes, you could have `TO_DATE('2016-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` although it's quicker to type the literal `DATE '2016-10-01'`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything to do with this question. I don't know any of the data types or values, or what 'not working' means. Seems like it should be a new question, with all relevant information included.

Comment: ok no issues..Thanks for your help